# How to setup RabbitMQ consumer in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rabbitmq

I want to consume messages from RabbotMQ using Spark 2 and Scala 2.11. I found [this library](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-rabbitmq). Also, I installed RabbitMQ on docker using:

```
docker pull rabbitmq
```

and launched the Docker container:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

However, I do not understand how to produce and consume messages. I expected that the approach would be pretty similar to Kafka queue. But RabbotMQ requires more parameters, such as `exchangeName`, `exchangeType`, `vHost`, etc. Where should I take these parameters from?

In the logs of RabbitMQ, I see the following info:

```
              Starting broker...
2018-01-23 15:18:40.633 [info] <0.183.0> 
 node           : rabbit@my-rabbit
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
 cookie hash    : WMiNo1v32m4elTFNfQ5yHA==
 log(s)         : <stdout>
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@my-rabbit
```

I checked `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` but it's empty.

```
val receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, Map(
      "hosts" -> hosts,
      "queueName" -> queueName,
      "exchangeName" -> exchangeName,
      "exchangeType" -> exchangeType,
      "vHost" -> vHost,
      "userName" -> userName,
      "password" -> password
    ))
    val totalEvents = ssc.sparkContext.longAccumulator("My Accumulator")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following class, which has the values that can be set for Rabbit.

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.ConfigParameters
```